# Faster alternative to ArchiveMount?

Tags: mount, tar

At the moment I am using `ArchiveMount` to mount a 123,000 kb archive that contains more then 3 million files inside. So far it has been mounting for 5+ hours and still isn't finished.

Is there a better way to mount a `.tar.gz` file? I am trying to mount to a folder, and uncompressed it takes a few gigs. I don't even need write mode, just read-only is sufficient.

Comment: There's also [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/); I have no idea if it'll perform better.

Comment: If your files were compressed as a squashfs module instead of as a tarball, then read-only access would be very quick - you just (loop) mount the squashfs module. Requires the squashfs-tools package.

Comment: I'm currently programming such a file system. Wait a couple of months and it's going to be there.

Comment: @FUZxxl  Well, its been 2 years, did you ever write this utility?

Comment: @cybernard FUSE frustrated me so much that I gave up on this project.  I hate this undocumented piece of shit.  I do keep this on the back burner and might take it back on later.

Answer (score 17):

I wrote a faster alternative [ratarmount](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount), which "works for me", because this problem kept bugging me.

You can install and use it like this:

```bsh
pip3 install --user ratarmount
ratarmount my-huge-tar.tar mount-folder
ls -la mount-folder # will show the contents of the tar top-level
```

When you are done you can unmount it like any FUSE mount:

```bsh
fusermount -u mount-folder
```

## Why is it faster than archivemount?

It depends on what you measure.

Here is a benchmark of memory footprint and required time for first mounting, as well as access times for a simple `cat <file-in-tar>` command and a simple `find` command.

[image: Benchmarks]

Folders containing each 1k files were created and the number of folders is varied.

The lower left plot shows error bars indicating the minimum and maximum measured times for `cat <file>` for 10 randomly chosen files.

### Pros

- Not shown in the benchmarks, but ratarmount can mount files with **preexisting index sidecar files** in under a second making it **vastly more efficient** compared to archivemount for every **subsequent mounts**.
- Ratarmount comes with a **progress indicator**, so that in contrast to archivemount, users do not have to try waiting for hours without getting any feedback.
- **Getting file contents** of a mounted archive is generally **vastly faster** than archivemount and fuse-archive and does not increase with the archive size or file count resulting in the largest observed speedups to be around 5 orders of magnitude!
- Mounting **bzip2** and **xz** archives has actually become **faster** than archivemount and fuse-archive with `ratarmount -P 0` on most modern processors because it actually uses more than one core for decoding those compressions. `indexed_bzip2` supports block **parallel decoding** since version 1.2.0.
- **Memory consumption** of ratarmount is mostly **less** than archivemount and mostly does not grow with the archive size.

  - The **gzip** backend grows linearly with the archive size because the data for seeking is thousands of times larger than the simple two 64-bit offsets required for bzip2. If this becomes an issue, you can increase the seekpoint spacing using `--gzip-seek-point-spacing <spacing in MiB>` to reduce the total amount of points and therefore data to be generated.
  - The memory usage of the **zstd** backend only seems humungous because it uses `mmap` to open.
    The memory used by `mmap` is not even counted as used memory when showing the memory usage with `free` or `htop`.
- For empty files, mounting with ratarmount and archivemount does not seem be bounded by decompression nor I/O bandwidths but instead by the algorithm for creating the internal file index.
  This algorithm scales **linearly** for ratarmount and fuse-archive but seems to scale worse than even quadratically for archives containing more than 1M files when using archivemount.
  Ratarmount 0.10.0 improves index creation upon earlier versions by batching SQLite insertions.

### Cons

- Unfortunately, **gzip** compressed TAR files are roughly one order of magnitude **slower** with ratarmount than archivemount during first time mounting.
  But, this slowdown will be amortized after the second subsequent mount thanks to the index file.
- **Getting a lot of metadata** for archive contents as demonstrated by calling `find` on the mount point is an order of magnitude **slower** compared to archivemount. Because the C-based fuse-archive is even slower than ratarmount, the difference is very likely that archivemount uses the low-level FUSE interface while ratarmount and fuse-archive use the high-level FUSE interface.

For more in-depth benchmarks, see the [Github page](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount/blob/master/benchmarks/BENCHMARKS.md).

Comment: How would the OP install *and use* this to solve their problem?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I added the install instructions from the github readme.md

Comment: ratarmount - good idea, but useless because of Python 2/3. But if you publish release package with static build of Python and its dependences, then it will be usefull.

Comment: @user1742529 You want to use ratarmount on system without any Python installation on it? Python is quite ubiquitous, it doesn't hurt having it installed. I could look into something like building an AppImage, FlatPak, or Snap, would that suffice in your opinion? Not sure if they work for this use case though.

Comment: @mxmlnkn yes, on system without any Python installation. you can pack Python+Modules+Ratarmount with something simple like `makeself` github.com/megastep/makeself , then make installation e.g. to `/opt` with one single command.

Comment: This is incredibly useful for working with Google Takeout archives and trying to figure out what on earth is using up so much space (e.g. mount and use `ncdu`). Thank you!

Comment: @user1742529 Probably too late, but I finally got around to create a self-contained [AppImage](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount/releases/download/v0.10.0/ratarmount-manylinux2014_x86_64.AppImage). You can find it under "Asserts" on the Github releases page.

Comment: @mxmlnkn Is there any script for creating such AppImage? I understand that most developers live in AMD64 only world, but I need other architectures too. )

Comment: @user1742529 The "recipe" if you can call it that can be found in the [Github Actions](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount/blob/995ae55e7cb12c5550114c89e7444db3aa6c63c9/.github/workflows/tests.yml#L252-L327). It is still not merged into master. I guess with Github Actions it might be possible to automatically build for non `x86_64`. Which platform do you require?

Comment: @mxmlnkn Thanks for link to Github Actions. IA-32 (x86), AMD64 (x86_64), ARM (ARM7), ARM64 (ARMv8).

Answer (score 10):

You could also create a compressed squashfs image

```
mksquashfs /etc squashfs.img -comp xz
mkdir img
mount -o squashfs,ro squashfs.img img
```

In order to do this you'll need to extract your tar.gz archvie.

The advantage is also that the image has better fault tolerancy than gz.

Comment: Nice! I got `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error` and had to mount it with `squashfuse -o allow_other derpynews.com.img derpynews.com` instead.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is with the format, the TAR (Tape ARchive) format is designed for sequential access, not random access. And gzip is a good complement to tar, since it is a stream based compression format, also not for random access.

So a high level tool that does not interact with the compressed blocks directly, will have to parse through the entire file every time it needs to read anything, first to get you the list of files, then perhaps the cache invalidates and it reads it again, and then for each file you copy off it might read through it again. You **can** make a tool that remembers the position of each file, and what blocks it needs to decompress to get it, but it seems that few have bothered with that.

If you want this to go faster, do a `tar tzf file.tar.gz > filelist`, open that file list in *vim*, *gedit* or whatever, remove the lines of files you do not need, save, and then extract them with `tar xzf file.tar.gz -T filelist -C extracted/`.

To get random access to a compressed file, you should use perhaps zip with posix extensions, rar, or as dru8274 suggested, squashfs, or even ZFS with compression turned on, or btrfs if btrfs has gotten compression to work at the time of reading.

Comment: To get random access to a compressed file, you could also use pixz.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need read-only access, check [Fuse-Archive](https://github.com/google/fuse-archive). readdir might not be that faster than archivemount, but for some workflows it is.

Answer (score 0):

This will not cover all use-cases as it restricts use to a text-editor. But, if you only care about read-access, you might find this helpful for some situations. `vim`, when run on a tarball will show you the content hierarchy of the archive (similar to how it will display a file hierarchy if run on a directory). By selecting one of the files in the list, it will open the selected file in a read-only buffer.

Again, this doesn't necessarily offer access to images or other media, but if all you need is to see the contents or access text-based files only, then this should be helpful.

**Note**: this will not work on all archive formats.

Comment: vim's built-in archive viewer still needs to scan through the whole file to obtain a listing, hardly faster than avfs and archivemount. and displaying such a huge listing of millions of lines is also terrible.

Answer (score 0):

My approach.  If you have enough free disk space on an external USB drive or external/secondary HDD drive with enough space, then consider just extracting your .tar.gz file. Thinking you probably don't want 3 million files on your main system disk, as that could slow things down. I'd recommend that the external disk in this case have a filesystem that handles a huge number of files easily: thinking ReiserFS, ext4 (with dir_index option), XFS, maybe BtrFS.  It could might take 1-2 hours to do the extract, but you could just go get lunch in the meantime or let it run overnight; when you come back, accessing the extracted files should be performant.

Comment: there is no need for an additional media, a loop device is sufficient.